# Is there an alternative to LaTeX which isn't whitespace sensitive?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs, code, sourcecode

I have been using LaTeX for about a year now, and I quite like it.

However, I like to space out my source code. In most languages, this doesn't cause an issue,
as extra newlines don't affect meaning.

However, in LaTeX, two newlines in fact changes the document, by creating a new paragraph.

I'm wondering, is there a way to turn this feature off in latex, and require me to specify new paragraphs manually? If not, is there an alternative to LaTeX (preferably similar i.e. still TeX based) which isn't so sensitive?

Comment: You can always specify new paragraphs by `\par`.

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Comment: You could say `\endlinechar=32`; this would avoid the problem of empty lines, but not that of spaces, of course. Ignoring spaces in TeX's source code would require you to manually insert some different character for it. The main problem is that in a printed document one *does* want spaces.

Comment: I like that solution. I don't really want to avoid spaces, manually inserting them would be a hassle. I guess to me they're less intrusive, since most languages use spaces to separate tokens anyways.

Comment: The other difference with spaces is that multiple spaces make no difference. I'm okay if newlines separate things, but I don't like that when I space the document for code readability it affects the layout.

Comment: @jmite Can you show a couple of examples of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The conversion of two consecutive newlines to a `\par` token comes from TeX's parser and so all formats of TeX (plain, LaTeX, ConTeXt) observe it too.

Note that `\par` gobbles all whitespace until the next non-whitespace token, so three or more consecutive newlines have the same effect as two: one new paragraph.  So if you want to have three blank lines before every `\section` and four before every `\chapter` you won't get multiple blank paragraphs.

The usual way to avoid unintentional whitespace is to use comment characters (`%`).  A comment character ignores all whitespace until the end of the line.  So lines that start with comment characters insert no whitespace.

```
Look
%
%
ma,
%
%
no
%
new
%
paragraphs!
```

[image: sample code output]

The only spaces in the above come from the newlines.  If you added comments at the end of the rest of the lines you would have no whitespace at all!

```
Look%
%
%
ma,%
%
%
no%
%
white%
%
spaces!
```

[image: sample code output]

Comment: This certainly works, and in all reality is what I will probably do. It just seems hacky and awkward, despite being the widespread solution.

Comment: @jmite: the only place I find it difficult is in macro programming, where a newline betwee opening brace and replacement text can introduce extra space. Someday we'll all be uising expl3 syntax for macros, though, and from what I understand all white space is ignored there. :)